C braced initializer for -non- array
Please consider the following absurd but compiling code:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *a, *b, *c, *d;

    void *the_good_array[] = { a, b, c, d };
    void *the_bad_array    = { a, b, c, d };

    return 0;
}

I accidentally produced something similar and, to my astonishment, it fully compiles.

Why does it compile?
What is { a, b, c, d } supposed to mean as an initializer for a non array? Without the braces, I would understand it's an accidental use of the , operator resulting in the value of the last element (d). But, braces? What are they supposed to mean here?

If possible, please refer to the C standard when answering.
Edit 1:
Compiles with both:
gcc -std=iso9899:1990 /tmp/bad_array.c     # gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14)`
clang -std=iso9899:1990 /tmp/bad_array.c   # Debian clang version 14.0.6

Edit 2:
Apparently
int i = { 0 };

is perfectly valid C.
I would like to know why but don't have the standard to read it.

This isn't valid C, it stops compiling if you add -pedantic-errors.

What compiler are you using?

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica Tried with both GCC 12 and CLANG 14

@HolyBlackCat AFAIK the fact that it does not compile under -pedantic-errors does not mean it is not valid C code. It only means it produces warnings and those warnings are considered errors by the compiler.

Have you seen these warnings?

@KamilCuk Yes: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer. This is what confuses me the most. Just tried int i = { 0 }; and it compiles without warnings! ???

You should use -Wall and check the warnings. The other question says what it is from the standard.

@ToniHomedesiSaun -pedantic-errors specifically enables warnings about standard non-conformance, and treats as errors only them. If it rejects a valid program, it's a compiler bug. You could be confusing it with -Werror, which would treat all warnings as errors.

"I don't have the Standard" Here you go: the draft of C23 (differences from the real published Standard will be minimal): https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf

@pmg Thanks! ___


What is { a, b, c, d } supposed to mean as an initializer for a non array?

Having multiple intializer elements for single object is a constraint violation. N2176 (C17 standard draft) §6.7.9 Initialization:

Constraints

No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being
initialized.


In this case it's depends on compiler what happens.

Why does it compile?

C compilers take backwards compatibility quite seriosly, and will accept a lot of code that would be considered invalid nowadays.

But, braces? What are they supposed to mean here?

Braces are allowed allowed even around single expression:

Syntax



initializer:

assignment-expression
{ initializer-list }
{ initializer-list , }


initializer-list:

designationopt initializer
initializer-list , designationopt initializer
...






With rules above, initializer can after a few steps be expanded to { assignment-expression }.

"In this case it's depends on compiler what happens" Since it's a constraint violation, compilers must at a minimum display a diagnostic message. If the compiler also chooses to generate an executable anyway, then all bets are off. It could be a documented compiler extension or it could be undefined behavior.

Any initializer may have braces.
You can just omit them. From https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11 :

The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.

Example:
int i = {1};

The compiler informs you that:
<source>:5:35: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [-Wexcess-initializers]
    5 |     void *the_bad_array    = { a, b, c, d };

Looks like the compiler chooses to ignore the "excess", taking only a.

Why does it compile?

The short answer: the compiler was created by people in the way that compiles it. The GCC compiler writers chose to handle excess elements in scalar initializer in this particular way.
The language-lawyer answer: the code is invalid. It breaks the "shall" from the link above:

The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression

From https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2 we know that:

If a ''shall'' or ''shall not'' requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime- constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

The behavior is not defined, which means that anything can happen. Compiling is "anything".

I believe that trailing elements is some gcc extension. Added to make bug-writing easier. Thx GNU C crew, helpful as always... For boring people who don't like extra unexpected bugs to spice up their lives, there's -pedantic-errors.
